# How do I create an uptime alert in pingdom without hardcoding the query parameters in http request?

Tags: pingdom

I am a novice Pingdom user ..I need to create an uptime check in Pingdom for a http get request which has request query string parameters ..
eg the request has parameters for center,query ,radius 
Appreciate any help in this regard

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Why not make up some values? `http://yourdomain.com/foo?center=1&radius=2`.
When creating your check in Pingdom, enter the full URL including the query part into the URL field.